# gzip compression is not working using MEAN STACK and LiteSpeed Server with cPanel access - mod deflate; mod gzip

Tags: apache, error-handling, gzip, cpanel, litespeed

I've been trying to compress my files using gzip but it's not working. I have tested the website on several gzip test sites and some says my website is gzipped but [www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/](https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/) says otherwise and my website

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file (not the root file but I have a similar one):

```
> RewriteEngine On
> # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] RewriteCond
> %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d RewriteRule ^ - [L] RewriteCond
> %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
> 
> # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html RewriteRule ^ /index.html
> 
> <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$"> Header set
> Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public" </filesMatch>
> 
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, POST, GET,
> DELETE, PUT, PATCH"   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "86400"
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers
> "append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,
> x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept,
> client-security-token, x-auth-token"
> #   Header always set Content-Length: totalBytes
> #   Header always set Content-Encoding: gzip </IfModule>
> 
> <IfModule mod_mime.c>  AddType application/x-javascript .js  AddType
> text/css .css </IfModule> <IfModule mod_deflate.c>  SetOutputFilter
> DEFLATE   <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI
> \.(?:rar|zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI
> \.(?:gif|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI
> \.(?:avi|mov|mp4)$ no-gzip dont-vary    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI
> \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary   </IfModule>  <IfModule mod_headers.c>  
> Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary  </IfModule> </IfModule>
> 
> <IfModule mod_deflate.c> <FilesMatch
> "\\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css|htm|jpg|png|jpeg|woff|woff2)$">
> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE </FilesMatch> </IfModule>
> 
> 
> <IfModule mod_deflate.c>   # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML
> and fonts   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff2  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE font/opentype   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> font/woff   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE image/x-icon   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE image/gif   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg,   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE text/css   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE text/plain   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
> 
>   # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)  
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html   BrowserMatch
> ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip
> !gzip-only-text/html   Header append Vary User-Agent
> 
> </IfModule>
> 
> # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:   # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/javascript   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/rss+xml   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/vnd.ms-fontobject   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-opentype   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-otf   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-truetype   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-ttf   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-woff   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-font-woff2   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/x-javascript   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> application/xhtml+xml   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml 
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE font/otf   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE font/woff2   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE image/jpeg   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE image/bmp   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg,  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
> text/html   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript  
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain   AddOutputFilterByType
> DEFLATE text/xml
> 
>   # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)  
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html   BrowserMatch
> ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip
> !gzip-only-text/html   Header append Vary User-Agent
> 
> # Or, compress certain file types by extension: <files *.html> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE </files>
> # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
> # Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language. <IfModule mime_module>   AddHandler
> application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml </IfModule>
> # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I am currently using cPanel. Server is Litespeed. I have enabled zlib.output.compression found in  `MultiPHP INI Editor`; also selected "Compress All Content" in `Compress All Content`. I have pretty much tried every solution I can possibly find online but gzip is still not working. I have also contacted my provider and they wanted me to check my code/script but I know my code works because it works locally and on another web hosting provider's site. The issue only arouse after I have changed it to this provider.

Comment: check with your own browser, see what it shows , I have seen sites serving brotli but test tools stick on gzip check

Comment: the thing is the browser is showing that some of the paths have been compressed but the entire website isn't when I check it on www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/